# Change screen Title on page load

Tags: acumatica

In Acumatica (AEF) is it possible to change the screen title programmatically. In my case, I want to change it on screen-load (based on a particular value). Example Change the Case screen title to Sub-Case at runtime, depending on a particular field of the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
Try setting the title of current SiteMap node in the graph constructor or graph extension initialize event:

```
PXSiteMap.CurrentNode.Title = "Test";
```

To my knowledge page Title is coming from the SiteMap. There's always the possibility to use JavaScript to modify the page and link title. Note that usage of JavaScript in Acumatica is usually discouraged.

In ASPX page, add a script element inside the root ASP container, get the title link element by class ID and change it's innerText property:

```
<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var title = document.getElementsByClassName("linkTitle")[0];
            title.innerText = "Test";
            document.title = "Test";
        }, false);
    </script> 

[...]
```