# Can we change site map name (Screen Name) based on the logic in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Do we have the feasibility to change the site map name (screen name) based on our Acumatica graph code?

Eg: I have created a new screen, where I have a button when I click on it should redirect with the "Sales Orders" screen but the name should not "Sales Orders" it should be my Custom name like (Test Sales Orders).

If we have this feasibility, please provide me the solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Title from your Graph or GraphExtension class, specifically within the Initialize event:

```
    public override void Initialize() {
        PXSiteMap.CurrentNode.Title = "Test Sales Order";
    }
```

See also this answer from HB_ACUMATICA: [Change screen Title on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44438779/change-screen-title-on-page-load/44439779#44439779)